# How to track the transaction status of bitcoin or ethereum?

Tags: bitcoin, ethereum

My project needs the user to send bitcoin or etherem to our designated address.My question is I need to track the transaction such as when a user sends some bitcoins or ethereum, how can i  check if the transaction has been completed or not.

Answer (score 0):

2 Ways:

- Use a 3rd party API service.
- Run your P2P node and watch the address.

Both methods will enable you to check if a transaction is confirmed or not.